# parse-server aggregate function returns null result

Tags: mongodb, parse-platform, parse-javascript-sdk

I am trying to use aggregate function on parse-server JS SDK

```
  var pipeline = [
    { group: { objectId: '$league_id'} }
  ];
  var query = new Parse.Query("Fixture");
  return query.aggregate(pipeline)
    .then(function (results) {
      return results;
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      throw error;
    });
```

When I run this functions it gives correct number of groups for league_id but it contains null data

```
{
    "result": [
        {
            "objectId": null
        },
        {
            "objectId": null
        }
    ]
}
```

What I am missing in here ? What can I do for getting other fields in result

Comment: Can you explain the schema of `Fixture` and what is the type of `league_id`?

Comment: It was a know issue https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server/issues/6312 It is my bad to not search enough. Problem solved thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there is already an issue for this https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server/issues/5989#issuecomment-526007093

It is fixed in 3.9.0